# Error: Syntax error before 'struct'

Tags: c, struct, stack

My code is basically functions used for making/using a stack. I've tried almost everything, but I don't know why my program is displaying this error:

> Error: Syntax error before 'struct'

```
#include "stack.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define CAPACITY 128

struct stack_struct {
    ElemType items[CAPACITY];
    int top;
};


StackPtr stk_create(){
    StackPtr s = malloc(sizeof(struct stack_struct));

    s->top = -1;  // stack initially empty
    return s;
}

// TODO
StackPtr stk_clone(StackPtr s) {
  return NULL;  // temporary placeholder
}

void stk_free(StackPtr s) {
    free(s);
}

int stk_push(StackPtr s, ElemType val){
    if(s->top == CAPACITY - 1)
     struct stack_struct * temp;
    temp = (struct stack_struct*)malloc(sizeof(struct stack_struct));
    s->top++;
    s->items[s->top] = val;
    return 1;
}

ElemType stk_pop(StackPtr s){
    if(s->top == -1)
        abort();  // library function which terminates program!!!
    s->top--;
    return s->items[s->top+1];
}

int stk_is_full(StackPtr s){
    return s->top == CAPACITY-1;
}

int stk_is_empty(StackPtr s){
    return s->top == -1;
}

int stk_size(StackPtr s) {
    return s->top+1;
}

void stk_clear(StackPtr s){
    s->top = -1;
}

void stk_print(StackPtr s) {
    int i;
    printf("\n----TOP-----\n");

    for(i=s->top; i>=0; i--) {
        printf(FORMAT_STRING, s->items[i]);
    }
    printf("---BOTTOM---\n");
}

int main() {

    StackPtr sptr;

    sptr = stk_create();

    stk_push(sptr, 1.7);
    stk_push(sptr, 3.14);
    stk_print(sptr);

    stk_pop(sptr);

    stk_print(sptr);

    stk_free(sptr);

}
```

Comment: typedef double ElemType;

Comment: which `struct` / line? `struct` appears quite a few times and I don't have the sources to actually successfully compile your code.  The contents of stack.h might be helpful as well.

Comment: Where you define StackPtr type?

Comment: line 35, in function stk_push below the "if-statement"

Comment: `struct stack_struct * temp;` does nothing, and the following line uses an undeclared `temp`. Are you missing a pair of curly brackets? (and some real use of that `temp` other than storing a buffer)

Comment: how would i declare temp? Yes I am.... lol thanks!

Comment: Your `temp` is declared in the block of the `if`, and is unseen to the code outside of it. Hence, the declaration is useless, and the following code can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

As I could see, function stack_push should look like this

```
int stk_push(StackPtr s, ElemType val){
    if(stk_is_full(s))
       return -1; // stack already full, we couldn't push new elem
    s->top++;
    s->items[s->top] = val;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: @user3539833 To implement dynamic stack you need a linked list. You can easily find examples of its c implementation in Net. For example, you could look [here](http://scanftree.com/Data_Structure/DynamicStack)

Answer (score 0):

I think error in this line (line 35 in your source code):

```
struct stack_struct * temp;
```

. Let's try

```
typedef struct stack_struct * temp;
```

or change declare struct

```
struct stack_struct {
ElemType items[CAPACITY];
int top;} stack;
```

and then call

```
stack* temp;
```

in line 35.